# How to remove horizontal scroll on span with twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-bootstrap and I keep seeing a horizontal scroll on the right most module (trending) part of this HTML page. When I reduce it from `span2` to `span1`, it makes the image tiny.  It doesn't seem like the image or text takes up the rest of the space either.  Any advice on how I can get rid of the horizontal scroll?

Additionally, when I make the width of the window smaller the small image thumbnails clash with the main video.  How do I fix this as well?

The page can be found [here](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1986445).

Comment: This question was indirectly helpful. Fixed the issue but right when I stuck in overflow-x: hidden; I realized that I had the 'find text' menu up which scaled the page just slightly (firefox).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want the `overflow-x` property

```
.my-class {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

There is also `overflow` (for vertical and horizontal overflow) and `overflow-y` (for just vertical overflow).

I know people don't like w3school but here are the values that overflow-x can have http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp

Answer (score 0):

For an inline solution:

```
<span style={{
  overflowX: "hidden"
}}>
```

`hidden` can also be `scroll`, `auto`, or `visible`